# Multiple wp_localize_script

Tags: wp-localize-script

Is it possible to localize a script more than once? I want to send two separate arrays of params.

Or is it only possible to localize a script once, in which case, I'll have to combine the arrays?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
wp_localize_script('my-handle', 'my_object1', $data1 );
wp_localize_script('my-handle', 'my_object2', $data2 );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be possible in WP 3.3:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/18480